# How to change swagger response for the class JSONObject

Tags: swagger

```
ResponseEntity<JSONObject> getJsonObject(@ApiParam(value = "class path",required=true) @PathVariable("hdfsPath") String hdfsPath)
```

I edit the response class "JSONObject" manually, but i do not know how to change swagger response for the class JSONObject, please help me!

```
  /hdfs/getJsonObject:
  get:
    summary: 
    description: 
    operationId: getJsonObject
    tags:
    - "Hdfs"
    parameters:
    - in: "path"
      name: "hdfsPath"
      description: 
      required: true
      type: "string"
    responses:
      200:
        description: ok
        schema:
```